# How to verify if fields are matching in two tables using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables: One table has fields like `city`, `zipcode` and `state`
and I have second table that has fields like `zipcode` `city` and `state`

I need to compare against the second table

For example:

When I run query against 1st table for 'Fresh Meadows', I get number of records:

```
Table1
city            zipcode     state       
Flushing         11351        NY 
Flushing         11354        NY
Flushing         11358        NY
Flushing         11365        NY
Flushing         11366        NY
...............................................
```

When running stored procedure against the main table, against which I compare, I get some number of records as well:

```
Table2
city            zipcode      state
Flushing        11370         NY
Flushing        11371         NY
Flushing        11372         NY
...............................................
```

I need to write a query that helps me to find those Cities in table 1 that do not match the zip codes in main table 2

How can I accomplish that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below joins on City, State, and Zip.  If the combination of those three fields is not in table B it will return that record from A.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM Table1 A
LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON
A.City = B.City AND
A.State = B.State AND
A.ZipCode = B.ZipCode
WHERE B.ZipCode IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

In words - Perform natural join between `table-1` and `table-2` on **"Cities"** with columns (Cities,Zipcode) - table2(Cities,Zipcode).